# How to boost/enhance the speed of the subtraction 2d array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

all!

I'm establishing a class with Python. In one of the function in the class, I need to subtract two large arrays, here is the code:

```
def gradient(x, h, data):
    u = (x - data) / h ** 2
    c = np.exp(- (h ** 2 / 2) * np.sum(u ** 2, axis=-1))
    c = c.reshape(-1, 1)
    g = -(u.transpose().dot(c)) / np.sum(c)

    return g
```

where *x* is a 1d numpy array of length *n*, data is an 2d numpy array with shape = (N, n) (in other word, a matrix of size N * n).

I test the speed of this function when *N = 30,000, n = 10,000*. The time cost is between 20s~100s (I also don't understand why the time cost could vary so much) And the 1st line -- subtraction of *x* and *data* is the main part of the time cost. (p.s. In numpy, if x is a 1d array of size n, data is a 2d array of size (N, n), then `x - data` will be automatically regard as the row-wise subtraction of *data* from *x*.)

```
from time import time

data = np.random.normal(size = 30000 * 10000).reshape(30000, 10000)
x = np.random.normal(size = 10000)
h = 0.2
start_time = time()
gradient(x, h, data)
print("Elapsed time is: ", time() - start_time)


Elapsed time is:  36.4828040599823
```

This is too low to serve the purpose of my class. Any method that could boost the speed of this 4-line function in the class?
The ideal time for this function should be around 2s~10s, is that possible to reach this goal? Great thanks in advance for any suggestions/ideas

Comment: Assuming optimal array storage and 4-byte floating-point values, the `data` array alone takes up 1.2 GB of memory. Couple that with the other intermediate arrays and the memory Python (and, you know, the rest of your computer) is using, and you've almost certainly exhausted your system's RAM. Dare I ask what requires this much data to be in memory at one moment?

Comment: " need to subtract two large arrays"... "where x is a 1d numpy array of length n, data is an 2d numpy array with shape = (N, n)" I don't understand what the result is supposed to look like, and I especially don't understand where all this squaring, exponentiation, summing and dot-product-taking is coming from if you just want to subtract the arrays. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide code that accurately reflects *the problem you are asking*, and/or fix your description of the problem.

Comment: One good idea might be to make the `size` keyword in `np.random.normal` the tuple `(30000, 10000)`, that way you don't need to reshape because the shape will be generated by default. Might make slight speed improvements.

Comment: Check a more modest size, say `N = 3000, n = 1000`.  Simply generating the start arrays starts killing my memory (on a rather modest machine).

Comment: @dsillman2000, he's not timing the `data` generation step (though on my computer that stuff does have a noticeable time lag). Yes, `normal` does take a tuple size, but that doesn't make a difference in the `gradient` step.

Comment: I have made some edit to this question: 1. the main time cost in this function is the first line: ```u = (x-data) / h ** 2```, that's why I care about the boost speed of subtraction. 2. 1d array - 2d array is allowed in python/numpy, when the size of 1d array is the same as one of the dims of 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

With smaller arrays (your's kills my memory):

```
In [1]: M, N = 3000,1000
   ...: data = np.random.normal(size = (M,N))
   ...: x = np.random.normal(size = N)
   ...: h = 0.2*10
```

I had to increase `h`, since otherwise I was getting divide by 0 warnings; `c` got too small.

time:

```
In [3]: timeit gradient(x,h,data)
43.6 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

lets check the steps:

```
In [5]: u=(x-data)/h**2
In [6]: timeit u=(x-data)/h**2
21.8 ms ± 79.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So that's about half of the total time; it is working with the `data` size.  You can't do much about that speed - at least not with `numpy` itself.

Only `u**2` works with the full `data` size; `sum` cuts it down substantially.

```
In [7]: c = np.exp(- (h ** 2 / 2) * np.sum(u ** 2, axis=-1))
In [8]: timeit c = np.exp(- (h ** 2 / 2) * np.sum(u ** 2, axis=-1))
15 ms ± 61.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [9]: c = c.reshape(-1, 1)
```

`dot` uses fast `BLAS` functions where possible, so has good speed, even when  multiplying a (1000,3000) with (3000).

```
In [10]: g = -(u.transpose().dot(c)) / np.sum(c)
In [11]: timeit g = -(u.transpose().dot(c)) / np.sum(c)
3.19 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [12]: u.shape
Out[12]: (3000, 1000)
In [13]: c.shape
Out[13]: (3000, 1)
In [14]: g.shape
Out[14]: (1000, 1)
```

`numba` and `numexpr` may improve speeds here, but I don't use them enough to explore that for you.

Times in seconds suggest you are pushing your memory's limits.